# Help. Unauthenticated package

Tags: package-management, debian

Hi I just done some stupid thing and allow unauthenticated packages. I used in the terminal command:

```
sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated
```

How to undo these changes?

Comment: That option should not be persistent between calls to apt-get. There are nothing to undo.

Comment: ok i write command bad and the correct command i used was "sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated." I want install git and in termnal is showing me something like this "the git package has no installation candidate".

Comment: That is a different problem that might occur even if you allow unauthenticated packages. It means that your client tried to look in every repository it knows about for a package alias named git, but found non at all. This usually means that either it has a different name on the listed repositories, or does not exist at all (either no package suitable for your os/architecture, or literally no version of it at all). Make sure the package name is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `--allow-unauthenticated` is a flag that will allow such packages only one time and it will be your command. It will not affect other future APT commands.

If you are worried about an unauthenticated package you have just installed, you may remove it like you would do with any other package.